# circular camera, simplest way?

Tags: godot-3, minimap

i have a minimap, inside a viewport inside a viewport container, everything folows the player, the player is at the center, the camera doesn't rotate with the player it rotates with the mouse, so looking at a cliff will not only rotate the primary camera to view the cliff but will also rotatethe minimap camera towards the cliff, this regardless of player direction.

so even if a player is facing backwards, if the camera is looking on the other way, so will the minimap too ...

but

it is square... i don't like it.

i need a round minimap like in shooter games.

i have no idea where to start.

Comment: Your question is how to crop the minimap to a circular shape?

Comment: kind of fixed it by covering the corers of the minimap with a circular health bar...

Answer (score 3):

Using [shaders](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/shading/your_first_shader/your_first_canvasitem_shader.html), you can cut off the corners of your rectangular map, making it a circle:

```
shader_type canvas_item;
void fragment(){
    COLOR = texture(TEXTURE, UV);
    // make the pixel completely transparent
    // if it's outside the radius of the circle
    COLOR.a = 1.0 - round(distance(UV, vec2(0.5, 0.5)));
}
```

Apply a [ShaderMaterial](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shaders/shader_materials.html) with that code to the UI node that displays the map.  If your map is made of multiple, complex UI elements, you may need to wrap them in their own Viewport and use a TextureRect with a ViewportTexture (then apply the shader to the TextureRect).  Below is an example of having a "Map" TextureRect that displays a ViewportTexture targeting the "MapViewport" viewport.

Before shader:

[image: without shader]

After shader:

[image: with shader]